# Convergence of measurable functions by two conditions

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions, pointwise-convergence

I have the following task from my textbook:

Let  $\left\{f_{n}\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of measurable function on $M$ with
$$
f_{n} \rightarrow f \text { a.s., }
$$
where $f$ is also a measurable function. Here, a.s. means almost surely (= almost everywhere).

Show: if there exists a nonnegative measurable function $g$ satisfying the following conditions:
$$
\left|f_{n}\right| \leq g \text { a.s. for all } n \in \mathbb{N}
$$
and
$$
\int_{M} g^{p} d \mu<\infty \text { for one } p>0,
$$
then
$$
\int_{M}\left|f_{n}-f\right|^{p} d \mu \rightarrow 0 \text { for } n \rightarrow \infty .
$$

---

These notations remind me a little bit of the Hölder inequality.

What I have got:

I thought that we have
$$
|f_n|^p \leq g^p a.s.
$$
Thus
$$
\int_M |f_n|^p d\mu \leq \int_M g^p d\mu \leq infty
$$

And as
$$
f_n \rightarrow f
$$
then the rest follows?

Answer (score 2):

For $p>1,$ the function $x\mapsto x^p$ is convex so $|f_n-f|^p=2^p\left|\frac{f_n}{2}+\frac{(-f)}{2}\right|^p\leq 2^{p-1}(|f_n|^p+|f|^p)$ so
$$
2^{p-1}(|f_n|^p+|f|^p)-|f_n-f|^p\geq 0.
$$
In the standard way that dominated convergence theorem is proven, just apply Fatou's lemma.

Comment: +1. It suffices that $2^{p+1}(|f_n|^p+|f|^p)-|f_n-f|^p\geq 0$, which can be obtained without using the convexity of $x\mapsto x^p$. For if $A=\max (|f_n|,|f|)$ and $B=\min (|f_n|,|f|)$ then $|f_n-f|^p\le (|f_n|+|f|)^p\le   (2A)^p\le$ $\le (2A)^p+(2B)^p=$ $2^{p+1}(|f_n|^p+|f|^p)$ because $\{A,B\}=\{|f_n|,|f|\}.$

Comment: In my comment (above) the term $2^{p+1}$ at the beginning, and also at the end, should be $2^p$.

Comment: I have completed my proof, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Only with the help of @zugzug and @DanielWainfleet I was able to complete the proof:

For $p>1,$ the function $x\mapsto x^p$ is convex, so
$$
|f_n-f|^p=2^p\left|\frac{f_n}{2}+\frac{ (-f) }{2}\right|^p\leq 2^{p-1} (|f_n|^p+|f|^p) \leq 2^{p-1} (|f_n|^p+|f|f|^p) -|f_n-f|^p\geq 0.
$$
Because of the Fatou lemma and the fact that $f_{n} \rightarrow f$ a. e. , we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_M 2^{p}|f|^{p} d\mu &=\int_M \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left (2^{p-1}\left (|f|^{p}+\left|f_{n}\right|^{p}\right) -\left|f_{n}-f\right| ^{p}\right) d\mu \\
& \leq \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_M 2^{p-1}\left (|f|^{p}+\left|f_{n}\right|^{p}\right) d\mu+\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left (-\int_M\left|f_{n}-f\right|^{p}d\mu\right) \\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_M 2^{p-1}\left (|f|^{p}+\left|f_{n}\right|^{p} \right) d\mu-\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_M \left|f_{n}-f\right| {p}d\mu \\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_M 2^{p-1} (2|f|^p) d\mu-\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_M \left|f_{n}-f\right|^{p}d\mu \\
&=\int_M 2^{p}|f|^{p}d\mu-\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_M \left|f_{n}-f\right|^{p}d\mu
\end{aligned}
$$
where the final equality follows from the theorem of dominated convergence.
As now
$$
\int_M 2^{p}|f|^{p} d\mu \leq \int_M 2^{p}|f|^{p}d\mu-\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_M \left|f_{n}-f\right|^{p}d\mu
$$
applies, shall:
$$\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_M\left|f_{n}-f\right|^{p} \leq 0$$ and the claim follows. $\quad \blacksquare$